# combine current timestamp with entered date in java

Tags: java, pojo

```
while(begin.compareTo(endDate)<0)
        {
            Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
            int total=3;
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            for(int d=0; d<=total; d++)
            {
            cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);
            timestamp = new Timestamp(cal.getTime().getTime());

            System.out.println(timestamp);

           System.out.println(new java.sql.Timestamp(begin.getTime()));

            begin = new Date(begin.getTime() + 86400000);
            list.add(new Date(begin.getTime()));
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
```

i want to merge current timestamp with the entered or start or begin date but it is giving ouput as

```
2016-04-11 15:30:26.717
2000-01-01 00:00:00.0
2016-04-11 15:32:26.717
2000-01-02 00:00:00.0
2016-04-11 15:34:26.717
```

and so on ..what should i do next please suggest.
Expected output should be like this:
Enter the Start Date: dd/mm/yyyy
01/01/2000
Enter the End Date: dd/mm/yyyy
02/01/2000

2000-01-01 15:48:17
           15:50:20
           15:52:02
till 12:00:00

2000-01-02 10:23:00
           10:25:00
again till 12:00:00

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with above code .. Please explain clearly with expected outcome

Comment: What do you mean by 'merge'?  Maybe give an example of what you would like the output to be.

Comment: It seems you want to add current timestamp to given date

Comment: i have start date and end date and now i have to print the timestamp with 2 min difference so i am not getting timestamp from start date to end date.

Comment: @Pooja can you please add expected output to your question

Comment: @pooja try to append the currrent timestamp with the entered one.

Comment: String getTimeStamp() {
  DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss");
  String timeStamp = format.format(new Date());
  return timeStamp;
} added this bt still i am getting that problem

Answer (score 0):

Just get the current time with the below statement and append it anywhere you want.

```
 new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())

 // outputs like 15:57:39
```

Comment: i am getting output like this:2000-01-01 00:00:00.0
2000-01-02 00:00:00.0
2000-01-03 00:00:00.0
2000-01-04 00:00:00.0
2000-01-05 00:00:00.0